# VB.NET Login Problems with SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, authentication, visual-studio-2015

So I am having problems with my login code on vb.net and was wondering could anyone can suggest what is wrong with my code?

The error I am getting is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class Login Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader

        Dim LogEmail As String
        Dim LogPassword As String

        LogEmail = txtLogEmail.Text
        LogPassword = txtLogPword.Text

        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\myAppointments\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmailAddress, Password FROM PatientDetails WHERE EmailAddress = '" & txtLogEmail.Text & "' and Password = '" & txtLogPword.Text & "'"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            lblLogin.Text = "Login Successful!"
        Else
            lblLogin.Text = "Login Unsuccessful! :("
        End If

        conn.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You do realize this is an SQL injection waiting to happen right? Parametize your query! Not to mention plain text passwords perhaps?

Comment: Can you help me in doing so?

Comment: [Goole is your friend](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=parametarized+queries+vb&*)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `[EmailAddress]` field or your `[Password]` field in your `[PatientDetails]` table is of type `text`.  You will need to change the underlying data type to `varchar` or `nvarchar` to use this query.

More importantly, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection since you are neither sanitizing, escaping, nor parameterizing those inputs.  Imagine if someone entered the following in the username box:

```
';DELETE FROM PatientDetails; --
```

when you checked their password, they just deleted your entire table...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Tim has said, there is no reason for either the EmailAddress or Password field to be of type `text`. Using `nvarchar(255)` for both should be sufficient.